# Permanent client TCP socket in Netty

Tags: java, jpos

I would like to use **Netty** as a client TCP socket. I write a client and server by **Netty** and it has worked well. Now, I have a requirement to have a permanent client socket to the server. I know that I can do it with a loop or some listener in **Netty** such as `ChannelFutureListener` but I want to know is there any built-in solution for my problem?

Actually, I have used **JPOS** in the past four years, and now I would like to know can I change the socket framework or not?

(My means specially to simulate `ChannelAdaptor` at **JPOS**)

Comment: Use you pure socket with owner protocol?

Comment: actually I want to use that